# How to make drawers close softly?

Tags: drawers

I've bought a [MALM drawer system](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/40053930/) that comes without any soft close-mechanism on the drawers. Is it possible to make or buy external silencers that i can attach to the drawers so they don't make so much noise when closing them?

And example on dampening for kitchen doors: http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/80126213/

Comment: do they pull themselves shut the last inch or so? if so then you just need an attachment point

Comment: No, i don't think so. Really basic shutting on those drawers

Answer (score 2):

You can either replace the slides with a soft closing model, or you could possibly shoe horn in a damper piston like this one made by Blum.

[image: Blum Piston]

They work in the same way as the ones in your link (those are made to attach to a hinge) but it can be recessed into a block or, in theory, drilled into a drawer side. The process would be to attach the piston in whatever fashion works with the pin pointed to the back of the cabinet. When you close the drawer the weight and momentum compresses the piston before it contacts the end of the slides travel, effectively softening the landing. You may have to apply a block on the back of the cabinet to give the piston a place to contact at the correct depth relative to the position of the drawer when it's fully closed.

Comment: Replacing slides, you you think these will work? http://www.amazon.com/SoftClose-Drawers-Retrofit-measuring-required/dp/B00JH81K6Y/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1415553198&sr=1-1-fkmr0&keywords=soft+close+slides+malm

Comment: @Haaakon Those might work if your slides are on the side of your drawer.  What type of slides does yours use?  What's the clearance on each side of the drawer?

Comment: It looks like those are appropriate for your application but I haven't worked with (or heard of) them personally so I can't guarantee their efficacy or if they'll work with your particular drawer configuration. It looks like if they do work, it will require a bit less dinking around to implement than the pistons, but they are considerably more expensive so....your call:)

Answer (score 2):

MALM drawers soft close available now in IKEA as an ad-on. Easy to install and very efficient.
Part No. MARKHUS  Soft closing device   604.265.71

https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/storage-furniture/chest-of-drawers/markhus-soft-closing-device-art-60426571/

https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/markhus-soft-closing-device__0677782_pe719070_s4.jpg